# Radio Transmition between Arduino Uno and Raspberry Pi 4 not working (using NRF24L01 module)

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, radio-transmission

I'm currently trying to send strings from my Arduino Uno to my Raspberry Pi 4 using the radio module NRF24L01, but it's not working.
I think the problem is in the raspberry part.
When I launch the program it starts receiving garbage data and not what my Arduino is transmitting.
Even if I turn the Arduino off, the raspberry continues to receive data.
[image]

[image]
This is how I connected the two boards.
This is the Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(9, 10);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setChannel(0x76);
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL);
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.powerUp();
}

void loop() {
  const char text[] = "HELLO";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  Serial.println("--> SENT");
  delay(1000);

}
```

This is the raspberry pi code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

#------------   SETUP RADIO LISTENER ------------------------------------------------
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pipes = [[0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]
radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0,17)
radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)
radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()
radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[0])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()
GPIO.cleanup()
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

while True: #LOOP FUNCTION
    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1/100)
    receivedMessage=[]
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print("--> {}".format(receivedMessage))
    print("Converting message...")
    string=""
    for n in receivedMessage:
        if(n>=32 and n<=126):
            string+=chr(n)
    print("--> {}".format(string))
```

All the libraries are installed correctly.
The only thing that raspberry pi catches is:

```
STATUS   = 0x03 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=1 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     =
 0xfdfdfdfdfd 0x7e7e7e7efc
RX_ADDR_P2-5     =
0xf8
0xf9
0xf9
0xf9

TX_ADDR      =
 0xfdfdfdfdfd
RX_PW_P0-6   =
0x80
0x8c
0x80
0x80
0x80
0x80

EN_AA        =
0x8f

EN_RXADDR    =
0x80

RF_CH        =
0x9f

RF_SETUP     =
0xff

CONFIG       =
0x9b

DYNPD/FEATURE    =
0x83
0x81

Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = 8 bits
PA Power     = PA_HIGH
--> [192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
--> 
--> [128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Converting message...
-->
```

It continues forever.
I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help?

Comment: P.S.:  could it be the 2.4GHZ WiFi at my house that is interfering with the module?

Comment: I watched this video to do everyhing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_68f-yp63ds&ab_channel=AlexanderBaran-Harper

Comment: [did u see this ?](https://imgur.com/WkFtGjT)

Comment: I didn't, but my connections are all good I think. I connected the VCC to the 3.3V and the GND to GND

Comment: I just found the website of this guy (http://thezanshow.com/electronics-tutorials/raspberry-pi/tutorial-34-35) and I copied the code from him, but the result is the same

Comment: The output is different now. I copied the code from the website and added a GPIO.cleanup() before the while loop. Now the output is Received: [155, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9] or [201, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13]

Comment: Also, if I had a time.sleep(1) at the end of the loop, after few seconds it prints: 
Received: [36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36]
Translating our received Message into unicode characters...
Our received message decodes to: $$$$$$

Answer (score 1):

1. the default SPI clock of the rapsberry is maybe too high for the arduino down this at 8Mhz
2. be careful with the use of `RF24_PA_MAX`, if the power supply is not able to deliver enough current then the module will not communicate for tests it is better to stay at `RF24_PA_MA`